# JS: Unable to get window.parent to use postMessage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, postmessage

So I have been following many tutorials on using `window.postMessage()` to communicate between a container `window` and its iframe content `window`.

However, I run into the issue where I cannot target the recipient's `window` onto which I could call `postMessage()`, or rather the object that I obtain is empty. Here are some explanations, and you can follow me by looking at the code in the [Github repo](https://github.com/jansensan/test-iframe-comm-with-post).

I have two projects, `iframe-content` and `iframe-container` that do exactly what you would expect. Each of these projects need to target a `window` object to be able to call `window.postMessage()`.

In the case of the container, running this code

```
var childWindow = document.getElementById('iframeContent').contentWindow
console.log('childWindow: ', childWindow);
```

does not result in an error, but the `window` object returned has no property whatsoever. [See the code](https://github.com/jansensan/test-iframe-comm-with-post/blob/master/iframe-container/src/js/services/post-office-service.js#L17).

Similarly, doing this in the `<iframe>` content

```
var parentWindow = $window.parent;
console.log('parentWindow: ', parentWindow);
```

does the same as explained concerning the container. [See the code](https://github.com/jansensan/test-iframe-comm-with-post/blob/master/iframe-content/src/js/services/post-office-service.js#L17).

See a screenshot of the empty `window` object I mean:

[image]

In both cases, calling the `postMessage()` function returns no error, but actually fails.

What may I have overlooked? What should I look into? Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('iframeContent').contentWindow.postMessage` return (without invoking parentheses!)?
The window object seems to be always empty in Chrome while showing some properties in Firefox.

Comment: @RainerRillke: I relied on you comment and checked in both FF and Safari, which I had forgotten to do. FF is ok like you say, Saf is complaining about security. Maybe providing info about the other window is the unsafe thing, so Chrome shows no error, but no content? I checked `postMessage` without paren's, and it shows `function () { [native code] }`. I added some logging, and It works fine now. I must have misunderstood my debug. Thanks!

Comment: feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score -1):

Sounds probably like you're try to access cross domain iframe. Make sure you set up the api with the correct origins and event listeners.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Remember the iframe needs a listener for the message

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I already have listeners on the current window https://github.com/jansensan/test-iframe-comm-with-post/blob/master/post-office/src/post-office.js#L84 I'll add an image to my original post to show what I mean with an empty recipient window.